# Problem During Retriving Data From database which stored using Summernote means in HTML Format in Sql Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I Used Summernotes editor in my Application and stored data in sql server database.
My data stored successfully which is in HTML Format
But I need to retrieve that data and its successfully fetching but in HTML Format
I Need to retrieve Data only not With Tags so please tell how to retrieve data only without html tags?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to strip all html tags in razor you can use regex in helper. Example:

```
@helper RemoveHtml(string text)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    {
        text = Regex.Replace(text, "<.*?>", String.Empty);
        <span>@text</span>
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello thanks for your solution and its working but i faced other issue. That is i get the data without the tags but data shows with &nbsp; where ever i used space that place shows &nbsp sp please tell me what to do next?

Comment: And Also facing problem for \n